# angularjs object is not a function error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to send a repeater array items to web api controller method as parameter. When I click the button containing the function its giving me this error in console and nothing happens.

```
object is not a function
```

I guess I'm passing the orders array in a wrong way. How to do that correctly.

My ng-repeat

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:800px" data-ng-model="orderProduct">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="order in orders">
                <td>{{selectedProduct.pname}}</td>
                <td>{{order.pid}}</td>
                <td>{{order.oid}}</td>
                <td>{{order.qty}}</td>
                <td>{{order.total}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" data-ng-click="addOrder()" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-disabled="!orders.length" value="Submit Orders" />
```

My controller method $scope

```
    $scope.addOrder = function () {
            var orders = this.orders;
            $http.post('/api/OrderDetails/', orders).success(function (data) {
                alert("Added Successfully!!");
                $scope.addMode = false;

            }).error(function (data) {
                $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding Order details! " + data;

            });
        };
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: will this work? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=m7KgcQQe

Comment: I recommend that you use the non-minimized version of angularjs during development.  Much easier to debug.

Comment: I recommend that you start using Chrome Dev Tools, Firebug, or IE dev tools, open up your source code and step through the debugger.  You will likely find something.

Comment: changed to nonminified version and got this in chrome http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=J3gvMqGz

Comment: But, why do you have `this.orders` instead of `$scope.orders`. Looks suspicious.

Comment: changed this.orders to $scope.orders, i guess it should be like that too. But the error persists.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/gM55EUMH2kdS4CoYGLsa?p=info

Comment: thanks people, after changing the function name from addOrder() to addorder(), that is after replacing the capital 'O' with small 'o' the error has gone and everything working smoothly. as far as I knew camelCase is supported javascript naming convention, why it was creating problem can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I figured from your plunk is that - the form-name and a controller's method name can not be the same. I changed the form-name from **addOrder** to **addOrderForm**
Once the names have changed, this works correctly.
Please see working plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CfaNY9z5vVMi5uqh5v7k?p=preview

PS: I've taken the liberty of adding some json and angular code to get the form working.

Comment: but your answer is more precisely described with the reason of why this happened. Thank you

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking for a while about the line

```
object is not a valid function
```

and the other error from firefox

```
fnPtr is not a function
```

It suddenly buzzed in my mind that there maybe something fishy with my function naming. I guess it's silly but after changing the function name from addOrder() to addorder(), that is after replacing the capital 'O' with small 'o' the error has gone and everything working smoothly. Peace!!